# Custom sort of strings in R

Tags: r, shiny

Is there a way to customize sort of words in R?

For example, I have a data frame `df` as shown below

```
col1    col2
sdf     1 Vin
fdf     3 Oiu
sadf    10 Lop
sdf     2 Koi
```

When I put his in

```
selectInput("id", "Label", choice = df$col2)
```

I get `1 Vin, 10 Lop, 2 Koi, 3 Oiu` as order. But I need `1 Vin, 2 Koi, 3 Oiu, 10 Lop`.

Is the above result possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `mixedsort()` from `gtools`.

```
library(shiny)
library(gtools)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("id", "Label", choice = mixedsort(as.character(df$col2)))
)
server <- function(input, output){}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use `selectizeInput` with this `score` option:

```
library(shiny)

score <- 'function(search_string) {
    return function(element) {
        return new Sifter([element]).search(search_string, {
            fields : ["label"]
        }).items.length;
    };
}'

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectizeInput(
    "id",
    "label",
    list("1 zzz", "2 zzz", "10 zzz"),
    options = list(
      score = I(score)
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output){}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

This will keep the order of the choices you supply (so you have to order them in your dataframe).